# Wrapping multiple elements with one tag in DOMdocument

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I'm kind of stuck with wrapping elements to one tag in php DOMdocument.
This is what I have:

```
<figure>
    <a href="">
    <img class=""></a>
</figure>
<figure>
    <a href="">
    <img class=""></a>
</figure>
```

And result should be:

```
<div class="new">
    <figure>
        <a href="">
        <img class=""></a>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <a href="">
        <img class=""></a>
    </figure>
</div>
```

I allready did all work with figures inside loop, but I can't figure out how to wrap all theese tags in one parent.
I know that I have to use appendChild(), but my selection is DOMNodeList and it cannot be appened. Maybe I'm missing something.
My code:

```
$dom = new DOMdocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);
$NewDiv = $dom->createElement('div');
$NewDiv->setAttribute('class','new');
$figures = $dom->getElementsByTagName('figure');
$NewDiv ->appendChild($figures);
$dom->appendChild($NewDiv);
```

Answer (score -1):

something like this? I do not clearly understand your problem..

```
echo'<div>'
include (yourphp.php);
echo'</div>'
```

Comment: You're not using `DOMDocument`.